# how to call a webservice when a specific page has loaded in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, web-services

I am trying to make a call to my web-service when a specific page has loaded namely "http://thankyou" I have tried doing this with javascript and the WordPress wp_enqueue_script() function.

```
<?php function myprefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'callApi', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-content/themes/storeone/js/Wp_callApi.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('callApi');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_enqueue_scripts' );?>
```

Here is the Javascript function

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { 
    CallApi(); 
});

    function CallApi(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "My Web-service",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Call successful");
            }
        }
     )}
```

how can I call my webservice once the thank you page has loaded?
Code Im trying to run in functions.php file

```
<?php function myprefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'callApi', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-content/themes/storeone/js/Wp_callApi.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('callApi');
}

if ( is_page("order-received"){
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_enqueue_scripts' );
}
?>
```

Comment: Can't you use is_page and set the condition? check this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Comment: Honestly i think that might work! Thank you @noobcode are you familiar with calling web services with .php? if you are could you please help me convert my CallApi function to php?

Comment: whats the issue you are getting?

Comment: Will get back to you now trying to call my function with the is_page  in the functions.php file

Comment: @noobcode, I have added the code im trying to use in the functions.php file but i keep breaking my site all im trying to accomplish is call my web service when the thank you page loads i cant seem to get it to work though and iv been stuck on this for a few days now

Comment: well without checking your full code.. can't do much

Comment: if you want then you can ping me on skype. donno if its legitimate to provide skype on stack overflow. Username:- live:avenirsoft